# Plain text inside align* environment

Tags: align

I have an align environment that contains two lines, and in between these lines I want to include some plain text on its own line, and it should be centered on that line.

```
\newcommand{\tu}{\uptau}
\newcommand{\sgm}{\upsigma}
\newcommand{\txtn}{\textnormal}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \tu \sgm_{r_1} \tu^{-1} = \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 2 3 4)(5 8 7 6)(5 3 2)(6 7 4) = (1 3 5 7)(2 8 6 4)} = \sgm_{r_2} \\
\txtn{and} \\
& \tu \sgm_{s_1} \tu^{-1} = \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 5)(2 6)(3 7)(4 8) = (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 8)} = \sgm_{s_2}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This results in the word "and" showing up all the way to the left, but I want it to be centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\intertext` along with `\centering`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\newcommand{\tu}{\uptau}
\newcommand{\sgm}{\upsigma}
\newcommand{\txtn}{\textnormal}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \tu \sgm_{r_1} \tu^{-1} = \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 2 3 4)(5 8 7 6)(5 3 2)(6 7 4) = (1 3 5 7)(2 8 6 4)} = \sgm_{r_2} \\
\intertext{\centering and}
& \tu \sgm_{s_1} \tu^{-1} = \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 5)(2 6)(3 7)(4 8) = (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 8)} = \sgm_{s_2}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Or, if you want tighter vertical spacing, include in preamble

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

and then in the document use

```
\shortintertext{\centering and}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution with `shortintertext`, and also another alignment on the `=` signs, which looks better, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makebox}
 \usepackage{upgreek}
\newcommand{\tu}{\uptau}
\newcommand{\sgm}{\upsigma}
\newcommand{\txtn}{\textnormal}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\tu \sgm_{r_1} \tu^{-1} & = \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 2 3 4)(5 8 7 6)(5 3 2)(6 7 4) = (1 3 5 7)(2 8 6 4)} = \sgm_{r_2} \\
\shortintertext{\makebox[\linewidth]{and}}
\tu \sgm_{s_1} \tu^{-1} &= \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 5)(2 6)(3 7)(4 8) = (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 8)} = \sgm_{s_2}.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\tu \sgm_{r_1} \tu^{-1} & = \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 2 3 4)(5 8 7 6)(5 3 2)(6 7 4) = (1 3 5 7)(2 8 6 4)} = \sgm_{r_2} \\
 & \makebox*{${}={}$}{and}\\
\tu \sgm_{s_1} \tu^{-1} &= \txtn{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 5)(2 6)(3 7)(4 8) = (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 8)} = \sgm_{s_2}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `array`. I also suggest a different way to cope with cycles in permutations.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for some context

\newcommand{\tu}{\uptau}
\newcommand{\sgm}{\upsigma}

%not \textnormal
\newcommand{\perm}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \begingroup\lccode`~=` \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\,%
  \catcode` =12 \scantokens{#1}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
\tu \sgm_{r_1} \tu^{-1}
  = \perm{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 2 3 4)(5 8 7 6)(5 3 2)(6 7 4)}
  = \perm{(1 3 5 7)(2 8 6 4)}
  = \sgm_{r_2} \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{and}} \\[1ex]
\tu \sgm_{s_1} \tu^{-1}
  = \perm{(2 3 5)(4 7 6)(1 5)(2 6)(3 7)(4 8)}
  = \perm{(1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 8)}
  = \sgm_{s_2}.
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

What does the magic `\perm` macro do? It changes the space to an ordinary printable character (like punctuation) and *redefines* it to do `\,`. Here I exploit the fact that the `\mathcode` of space is set to `"8000` in the LaTeX kernel.

In any case you should never write something like

```
\txtn{(1 2 3 4) = (2 3 4 1)}
```

because the semantics of your document would be ruined. You mean

```
\txtn{(1 2 3 4)} = \txtn{(2 3 4 1)}
```

but even if you choose to stick with `\textnormal` you should properly denote permutations as such, so do `\newcommand{\perm}{\textnormal}` if you prefer and write the above as

```
\perm{(1 2 3 4)} = \perm{(2 3 4 1)}
```

The fact that the output of the equals sign is the same is not relevant; the *spaces* around it would be different.

Here's a picture of the output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but probably too advanced and intricate for my purposes.

Comment: @Junglemath Well, at least the `array` is not too advanced.